# Css animation on external file not work. but normal style work?

Tags: css, css-animations

i want to make image preview on my register page. and i use  to use my external css called `index.css`. earlier it fine for my input, button and other else. And also for image preview style, its work. I also use w3School css. but some reason. it doesnt work for animation (on external css only).

here my html code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/css/index.css">
<label for="harga">Harga</label> <!-- its just one of my input that css work. -->
          <input type="text" id="harga" name="harga" placeholder="Harga">

          <span style="float: left;margin-bottom: 10px">
            <div class="loader " id="loaderImg" style="width:80px;height: 80px;display: none ">
            </div>
          <img src="../assets/pic/produk/<?php echo $gambar; ?>" class="w3-circle w3-margin-right" id="fotoView" style="width:80px;height: 80px ">

          </span>
          <span style="float: left  ">
          <input id="foto" class="w3-white" type="file" name="foto"  title="foto" style="border:none;width: 100%; margin-top: 15px; padding:5px" onchange="previewImage()"/>
        </span>
```

here my css code

```
input[type=text], input[type=password] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}/* its normal css style that work */
/* loader not work in external css */
.loader {
  border: 8px solid #a3a199;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 8px solid black;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite; /* Safari */
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

/* Safari */
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

and here js for my img preview

```
function previewImage() {
    document.getElementById("fotoView").style.display = "none";
    var loader = document.getElementById("loaderImg");
    loader.style.display = 'block';
    var oFReader = new FileReader();
     oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("foto").files[0]);

    oFReader.onload = function(oFREvent) {
      document.getElementById("fotoView").src = oFREvent.target.result;
      loader.style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById("fotoView").style.display = "block";
    };
  };
```

thanks

Comment: How about href="~/css/index.css" ?

Comment: Is your "assets" folder is inside to your main directory?

Comment: [link](https://i.imgur.com/trLBxQI.png) here my pic of my directories in sublime 3